# How to add custom script statements to a gitlab job template?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to create a common `.deploy` template.

Every job that inherits from this template should be able to add some custom `script` logic **in between** the script from the inherited template. But how?

Example:

```
.deploy
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  before_script:
    - ...
  script:
    - touch .env
    - echo "SOME_COMMON_KEY=VALUE" >> .env
    - $$PSEUDOCODE / PLACE YOUR CUSTOM LOGIC HERE
    - ssh -i $SSH_ -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" $USER@$SERVER
    - scp -i $SSH docker-compose.yml .env $USER@$SERVER:~/test/
    - ssh -i $SSH $USER@$SERVER "docker-compose up"...
    
    
deploy_test:
  extends: .deploy
  variables:
    USER: test
    SERVER: test
  script:
    #TODO how to add custom statements in place of the $$PSEUDOCODE ?
    
    
deploy_prod:
  extends: .deploy
  variables:
    USER: prod
    SERVER: prod
  script:
    #TODO how to add custom statements in place of the $$PSEUDOCODE ?
```

So how could I add some custom statements in place of the `$$PSEUDOCODE` line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do is use `eval` on an environment variable.

```yaml
.deploy:
  # ...
  variables:
    USER_SCRIPT:
      value: ""
      description: "The contents of this variable will be executed with `eval` during the job script."
  script:
    - touch .env
    - echo "SOME_COMMON_KEY=VALUE" >> .env
    - eval "${USER_SCRIPT}"
    # ...
```

Another way users can insert logic in an extended job before or after `before_script` and `script:` is to use a `!reference` tag.

For example, to insert logic after `before_script:` but before `script:`

```yaml
another_job:
  extends: .deploy
  before_script:
    - echo "additional steps before before_script:"
    - !reference [.deploy, before_script]
    - echo "Additional step after before_script"
  script:
    - echo "Additional steps before script:"
    - !reference [.deploy, script]
    - echo "Additional steps after script:"
```

Comment: As I was looking for a way that also works with multiple files, the  `!reference` approach worked!

Answer (score 1):

Could you have the same code shared by your 2 jobs ? If yes, you can do it using [YAML anchors for script](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#yaml-anchors-for-scripts)

In your example, it can give :

```
.pseudo_code: &pseudo_code
  - echo "Hello $USER on $SERVER"

.deploy:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  before_script:
    - ...
  script:
    - touch .env
    - echo "SOME_COMMON_KEY=VALUE" >> .env
    - *pseudo_code
    - ssh -i $SSH_ -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" $USER@$SERVER
    - scp -i $SSH docker-compose.yml .env $USER@$SERVER:~/test/
    - ssh -i $SSH $USER@$SERVER "docker-compose up"...

deploy_test:
  extends: .deploy
  variables:
    USER: test
    SERVER: test

deploy_prod:
  extends: .deploy
  variables:
    USER: prod
    SERVER: prod
```

Comment: Unfortunately yaml anchors don't work when using multiple files, which is what I want. Apart from that it would be a good solution.